# Can you save the inferences/predictions on a list and use adam optimizer in each of them after

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow and in my current project I can't inmediately calculate the loss after a prediction/inference but rather every 2 or 3 predictions, so I was thinking in saving the tensors of each prediction in a list and running them trough the optimizer after.

I am new to tensorflow and not very familiarized with it so if there is no way to do this, other ways to tackle the problem are welcome.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

why you can calculate the loss?
If I understand your question right. your situation is very similar to in-graph distributed model. let each GPU/server compute a batch then gather all inference and loss , compute their average, then update variable.

Comment: The reason why I can't calculate the loss unless I do 2 or 3 inferences is because I just don't get to know if it was a good prediction until I take those 2 or 3 steps. I could "solve" my problem with graph search but the solution would still be very inferior to what I could get from a neural network, I just don't want to get into many details. But if the way I am trying to do it does not work then yeah I will try something with the average as you suggest.